# fswatch parsed argument not returning expected value?

Tags: python-3.x, fswatch

I might misunderstand the `xargs -I {}` parsed argument of `fswatch`. This should return the file path of any new events in my specified directory, correct?

My command below is intended to watch `/my/path/to/watch` and trigger `my_script.py` when a new event occurs in `/my/path/to/watch`. `my_script.py` requires the file path associated with the new event, which is what I thought I was passing with `{}`.

My command:

```
fswatch -0  /my/path/to/watch | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} python my_script.py {} > fswatch.output &
```

In `my_script.py`, I have

```
import sys
print sys.argv[0]
```

But this just returns `my_script.py` where I’m expecting it to return the file path associated with the new event in `/my/path/to/watch`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are executing a program from your terminal, the first arguments will always be the name of your program, meaning sys.argv[0] will be the name of your script. What you want to use would probably be sys.argv[1], as everything after sys.argv[0] would be the actual parameters passed to the script.

You could look at it like this:

```
$ python my_script.py foo var
```

sys.args would look like this:

```
|     0        |  1  |  2  | 
| my_script.py | foo | var |
```

Basically, sys.args[0] would be the name of your script and sys.argv[1] and so on would be the actual parameters passed to it.